# Verificacao da existencia de um objeto em um arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Tenho uma classe `PessoaFisica` e uma classe `PessoaJuridica`, ambas herdam da classe `Cliente`, cujo atributo identificar é o código.

Estou criando um método para verificar se já existe o elemento na lista(conferindo o codigo), e se nao existir adicionar o obj passado como parametro.

Classe cliente :

```
public class Cliente implements Serializable {
int codigo;
private String nome;
private String endereco;
private String telefone;
private String Tipo;

public Cliente(int codigo, String nome, String endereco, String telefone, String Tipo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
    this.nome = nome;
    this.endereco = endereco;
    this.telefone = telefone;
    this.Tipo = Tipo;
}

public int getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getEndereco() {
    return endereco;
}

public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
    this.endereco = endereco;
}

public String getTelefone() {
    return telefone;
}

public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
    this.telefone = telefone;
}

public String getTipo() {
    return Tipo;
}

public void setTipo(String Tipo) {
    this.Tipo = Tipo;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;
    hash = 89 * hash + this.codigo;
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

 if(this.getCodigo()==((Cliente)obj).getCodigo()){
     return true;
 }
        return true;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return   "" + codigo + ";" + nome + ";" + endereco + ";" + telefone + ";" + Tipo + ';';
}
```

O list se encontra na classe dados

o metodo e o seguinte

```
public void salvar(Cliente obj){

    if(Dados.listaClientes.contains(obj)!= true)
    {
        Dados.listaClientes.add(obj);
        System.out.println("item adicionado");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("impossivel adicionar");

    }
}
```

estou substituindo o metodo equals na classe cliente da seguinte maneira

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
if (this == obj) {
return true;
}
if (obj == null) {
return false;
}
if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
return false;
}

 if(this.getCodigo()==((Cliente)obj).getCodigo()){
 return true;
 }
      return true;
 }
```

nao estou tendo erro de compilaçao, mas simplesmente o metodo nao funciona, adiciona mesmo com elementos em codigos iguais

assim esta meu teste

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
{
{

        DaoPessoaJuridica dao = new DaoPessoaJuridica();

     PessoaJuridica c1 = new PessoaJuridica(10,"Daniel","ovidio vilela","993911490","F","46353698895",151515);
     PessoaJuridica c2 = new PessoaJuridica(10,"Daniel","ovidio vilela","993911490","F","4635369895",151515);
    PessoaFisica c3 = new PessoaFisica(10,"Daniel","ovidio vilela","993911490","F","4635369895");
       dao.salvar(c1);
       dao.salvar(c2);
       dao.salvar(c3);

     // Dados.listaClientes.add(c1);

        System.out.println(Dados.listaClientes.toString());

}  
    }}
```

alterei meu atributo código para

```
 private Integer codigo;
```

e usei o seguinte metodo,na comparacão de objetos do mesmo tipo ele se sai bem, porem quando vou comparar uma pessoa fisica e uma pessoa juridica de mesmo codigo, ele me deixa adicionar, oque nao deveria acontecer

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Cliente cliente = (Cliente) obj;
    if (codigo == null) {
        if (cliente.codigo != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!codigo.equals(cliente.codigo))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

consegui fazer funcionar comparando objetos diferentes também, porém usando somente o seguinte código no equals

```
@Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
 if(this.getCodigo()!=((Cliente)obj).getCodigo()){
 return false; }
 if(obj==null) 
 return false; 
 if(this==obj) return true;
 return true;
 }
```

esse código pode me resulta em algum problema futuro ?

Comment: Adiciona a classe cliente completa ai editando a pergunnta.

Comment: pronto adicionei ( o to string esta adicionando ; em todos os atributos pra posterior gravacao em arquivos txt)

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro declara seu identificador como:

```
//objeto do tipo inteiro    
private Integer codigo;
```

Depois substitui seu método equals por:

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Cliente cliente = (Cliente) obj;
        if (codigo == null) {
            if (cliente.codigo != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!codigo.equals(cliente.codigo))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

E o seu hashCode por:

```
@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int hash = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = hash * result + (codigo == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: /*  if (codigo == null)-- bad operant types for binary operator '==' {
        if (cliente.codigo != null)-- mesmo erro
        return false;
        } else if (!codigo.equals(cliente.codigo))-- int cannot be dereferenced
        return false;
        return true;*/
estou tendo o seguinte erro nessas linhas -

Comment: é porque estamos tentando comparar um int com um objeto, vou editar na resposta.

Comment: editei na pergunta o resultado